Estimate the limit of a probability $p_m$ derived from a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $X_n$.
For problem"Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are i.i.d. random variables that are uniform on the set $\{1,2, \ldots, N\}$. Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. For a given $m \geq 0$ let $p_m$ be the probability that the number $m$ shows up at some point in the infinite sequence $S_1, S_2, S_3, \ldots, S_n, \ldots$ Show that $\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} p_m$ exists, and find its value."
I tried
$$
\begin{align}
p_{m} & = P(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}_{+}, S_{n} = m)  \\
 & = P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ S_{n} = m \} \right) \\
 & \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\{ S_{n} = m \})
\end{align}
$$
and by law of total probability
$$
\begin{align}
P(\{ S_{n} = m \})  & = \sum_{x_{1}+x_{2}+\dots+x_{n}=m, x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n} \in \{ 1,2,\dots,N \}} P(X_{1} = x_{1},X_{2} = x_{2},\dots,X_{n} = x_{n})  \\
 & = \sum_{x_{1}+x_{2}+\dots+x_{n}=m, x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n} \in \{ 1,2,\dots,N \}} \frac{1}{N^{n}}
\end{align}
$$
And now I want to estimate $P(\{ S_{n} = m \})$. But I get stuck here (Using generating functions seems to be complicated, so I don't know whether it is a good entry. Or maybe we can use limit theorem to estimate? I'm not sure about that.)
Can anyone give me some ideas about the estimate above? Or is there any better ways to estimate $p_m$? Thanks!

This answer proves a more general fact; if $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is any iid sequence, the the limiting probability that $S_n$ attains the value $m$ is $1/\mathbb E[X_1]$, as $m⟶ \infty$.

Step 0. (Heuristics) We first give a heuristic argument:

The set $A = \{ S_n : n \geq 1 \}$ has "average density" that is reciprocal to $\mathbb{E}[S_1] = \frac{N+1}{2}$. Then for large $m$, we can expect that $p_m = \mathbb{P}(m \in A)$ is approximately $\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[S_1]} = \frac{2}{N+1}$.

Step 1. (Generating function) Let's make this heuristic rigorous. We let $S_0 = 0$ and redefine $(p_m)$ as
$$ p_m = \mathbb{P}(m = S_n \text{ for some } n \geq 0). $$
Note that this does not alter the values of $p_m$ for $m \geq 1$, and only introduced the new term $p_0 = 1$ that does not affect our analysis of the limiting behavior of $p_m$.
Now, since the events $\{S_n = m\}$, $n \geq 0$, are mutually exclusive, we actually have
$$
\begin{align*}
p_m = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(S_n = m).
\end{align*}
$$
So, the generating function of $p_m$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
f(z)
:= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} p_m z^n
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(S_n = m) z^m \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[z^{S_n}] \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[z^{S_1}]^n \\
&= \frac{1}{1 - \mathbb{E}[z^{S_1}]}.
\end{align*}
Step 2. (Analyzing GF) Now we focus on the denominator. If $|z| \leq 1$, then the identity
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \lvert z^{S_1} - \mathbb{E}[z^{S_1}] \rvert^2 \right]
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \lvert z^{S_1} \rvert^2 \right] - \left| \mathbb{E}[z^{S_1}] \right|^2 \\
&\leq 1 - \left| \mathbb{E}[z^{S_1}] \right|^2
\end{align*}
$$
tells that $\left| \mathbb{E}[z^{S_1}] \right| \leq 1$ with the equality if and only if $|z| = 1$ and $z^{S_1}$ is constant $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. In OP's case, this means that $z = z^2 = \cdots = z^N$ holds, hence $z = 1$ is the only choice.
The upshot of this observation is that the only pole of $f(z)$ belonging to the closed disk $|z| \leq 1$ is the pole at $z = 1$. Moreover,
$$ \lim_{z \to 1} (1-z)f(z)
= \lim_{z \to 1} \frac{1 - z}{1 - \mathbb{E}[z^{S_1}]}
= \lim_{z \to 1} \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[S_1]}, $$
hence $z = 1$ is a simple pole of $f(z)$. Consequently, we can write
$$ f(z) = \frac{p}{1-z} + g(z) $$
with $p = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[S_1]}$ and for some rational function $g(z)$ whose poles all lie on $|z| > 1$. In particular, if we expand $g(z)$ as the power series $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$ about $z = 0$, then $c_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $f(z)$ is written as
$$ f(z) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (p + c_m)z^m. $$
Step 3. (Conclusion) Combining altogether, we obtain $ p_m = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[S_1]} + c_m $ and therefore
$$ \lim_{m\to\infty} p_m = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[S_1]} = \frac{2}{N+1} $$
as claimed.

I understand the answer. But why did you think of considering the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at $z=1$? Is the correct order to first guess the form of $f(z)=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} (p+c_m)z^m$ and then follow the previous derivation process to validate it?

@Furby, I didn't consider the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at $z=1$. Rather, I performed partial fraction decomposition of $f(z)$.
